# why sourceTree push automatically files that have local changes?

Tags: c, eclipse, git, version-control, atlassian-sourcetree

I work with git on a certain branch.

I have edited `.cproject`

I used sourceTree to pull from the remote and some changed were merged and pushed automatically.

But why did files with local changes didn't ask for resolving merge conflicts?

[image]

Comment: If you have a tool that automatically *pushes* when you do a *pull*, that's pretty scary!

Comment: I used SourceTree for several months last year on a project, and I don't think it ever automatically `push`ed. Did you configure it to do this somehow?

Comment: @Chris, no. As a prof - it usually ask me to do stage before pull (otherwise changes will be overridden) or shoe me merge conflicts

Comment: @EladBenda, staging won't generally cause anything to be `push`ed, though. The advice to commit or stash your changes before `pull`ing is good. (As a side note, I generally prefer to `fetch` instead of `pull`, which does not merge my upstream branch into my local one. That way I can handle the merge manually.)

Comment: I don't see anything in your screenshot showing a push. Are you sure it pushed? Do you see your local changes merged into the upstream repository?

Answer (score 0):

If the changes you are illustrating didn't result from a *concurrent* modification, then any changes from remote can be automatically applied and merged into the local branch.
There wouldn't be any conflict, and you would see the diff you mention between the new local version and its parent commit.

By "concurrent", I mean modification done, *since the last pull*, in *both* branches, the local one (for instance `master`), and `remote/master`.